# android: after logged in facebook sharing not working Access_token is empty

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token, facebook-sharer

Hi all am posting customized data's on public facebook wall. This is working fine on devices that doesn't have facebook app installed. But on device with facebook installed the `access_token` is empty and i can't share the text.

```
 new Session(UserShareActivity.this).openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(UserShareActivity.this).setPermissions(PERMISSIONS).setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
                postParams.putString("message", getIntent().getStringExtra("message"));
                postParams.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());
                Log.d("pageID", prefs.getString(Strings.pageID, ""));
                Log.d("getAccessToken", "" + session.getAccessToken());
                Request request = new Request(null, prefs.getString(Strings.pageID, "") + "/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
                RequestAsyncTask newtask = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                newtask.execute();
            }
        }
    }));
```

`OnActivityResult()` method to pass call back:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try{
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```